# Imagem na URL do Image.network do flutter não funciona no dispositivo físico

Tags: api, flutter, dart

Fiz um app básico, pois até então, eu só usava `Image.asset()` para colocar imagem, agora eu fui colocar `Image.network()` e a URL e funcionou no AVD que criei, mas quando eu faço o APK e instalo no meu celular, não funciona as imagens do `Image.network()`.
Agora mesmo eu coloquei para rodar o meu app no meu celular físico por fio e as imagens carrega, mas quando eu realmente instalo(APK) não funciona.
Isso pode ser um erro do meu celular?
E tabém, quando eu fiz um app com uma API, só funcionou no AVD, quando eu instalei no meu celular não rodou também.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "asdas",
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              text: "Home",
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.file_download),
              text: "Download",
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("lorem ipsum dolor"),
                Image.asset(
                  "images/judeu.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Image.network(
                  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Adicionou as permissões de acesso a internet no `Android Manifest`?

Comment: Olá, não, não coloquei.

Comment: Onde que eu coloco isso?

Comment: No arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` localizado em `android/app/src/main` adicione esta linha dentro da tag `<manifest`:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Funcionou, eu não sabia disso.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Sem problemas. Para ajudar outras pessoas eu vou postar como resposta e vc poderá sinalizar como solução válida ajudando outros membros da comunidade caso tenham a mesma dúvida que você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Problema ocorre por não ter a permissão de acesso a internet configurada. Em modo `Debug` o framework já tem tratamentos para bloquear este acesso. Já no modo `release` é necessário informar. Para fazer isso adicionar a linha abaixo dentro da tag `<manifest` do arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` que fica localizado em `android/app/src/main`.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Exemplo**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exemplo.flutter">

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <!-- Adicionar esta permissão -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Exemplo"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```